# get a specific number in a string

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying to parse a text and get a value from a text like:

```
Page 1 of 6
```

I am looking at extracting the end number using java.
so my out put in this case should be 6.

is there any java string functions I can use? (or) any other way?

Comment: Is the text always going to be the same?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes I tried but not getting the value..now with what Dan said  Yes. I was using split

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
String s = "Page 1 of 6";
String[] values = s.split(" ");
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(values[values.length - 1]));
```

Comment: Thank you This worked. I was not using Parserint :-) I am closing the Question

Answer (score 15):

You could use a regular expression for this (it's safer than using for example `String.split`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "Page 1 of 6";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("Page (\\d+) of (\\d+)").matcher(text);

    if (m.matches()) {
        int page  = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        int pages = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));

        System.out.printf("parsed page = %d and pages = %d.", page, pages);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
parsed page = 1 and pages = 6.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is basic string manipulation. what you can do is this..

```
    String pageNumberString = "Page 1 of 6"; 
    int ofIndex = pageNumberString.indexOf("of"); 
    int pageNumber = Integer.parseInt(pageNumberString.substring(ofIndex + 2));
```

I think this should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)$");
Matcher m = p.match("Page 1 of 6");
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regular expression, as long as the format of your numbers is going to stay similar.

This one for example, will match any string with 2 numbers (seperated by any non-digit character), and capture the 2 numbers.

```
(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)
```

Note: this will match some weird things like "Page1of2".  It also won't match negative numbers.  Not that you expect to ever get a negative page number.